# Can not retrieve user's location using Mapbox API

Tags: android, mapbox

The picture says it all. I am currently building an app that is using Mapbox API to retrieve user's location and now it does not give any location at all.

I even tried their demo app and the bug is still persisting. The image is a screenshot that I took from their demo app itself:

[image]

Comment: Try using examples found in the https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-plugins-android/tree/master/plugin-locationlayer repo. Another option would be updating Google Play location services to the newest version manually.

Comment: Code would help to find the issue

Answer (score 0):

As Łukasz Paczos said, try following the code found at the link below
https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-plugins-android/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/mapbox/mapboxsdk/plugins/testapp/activity/location/LocationLayerModesActivity.java